# Limit packet rate, open connections, and IP addresses

Tags: iptables, linux-networking, traffic-shaping, tc, traffic-filtering

On Linux, can I use tools like `tc`, `iptables` or others to control/shape network traffic on a network interface, for the following purposes:

1. Control the network packet number rate (or the total number).
2. Control the number of IP addresses connected (sent).
3. Control the total number of open TCP connections (per second).

If so, how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an answer for nr. 2 (see below). 
For 1. and 3. you can use the *limit* module:

1. Control the network packet number rate:

   ```
   iptables -A OUTPUT -m limit --limit 10/s -j ACCEPT
   ```
2. Control the total number of open TCP connections (per second):

   ```
   iptables -A INPUT -m state -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 10/second -j ACCEPT
   ```

**Alternatively** you can use the *hashlimit* module:

1. Control the network packet number rate:

   ```
   iptables -A INPUT -m hashlimit -m tcp -p tcp --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-srcmask 32 --hashlimit-above 10/sec --hashlimit-burst 2 --hashlimit-htable-expire 30000 --hashlimit-name pktlimit -j DROP
   ```
2. Control the total number of open TCP connections (per second):

   ```
   iptables -I INPUT -m hashlimit -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 --hashlimit-above 10/sec --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-name connlimit -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j DROP
   ```

You can monitor how hashlimit is performing for you by looking at:

```
cat /proc/net/ipt_hashlimit/pktlimit
cat /proc/net/ipt_hashlimit/connlimit
```

*EDIT*:

In a world where NAT is dominant, does it really make sense to limit the number of source IP addresses like you want to do in nr. 2? I think it makes more sense to limit the total number of open TCP connections, like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 10 --connlimit-mask 32 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

Comment: iplimit is not available in my version...

Comment: it would help to know which is 'your version' :)

Comment: iptables v1.6.1 on Ubuntu 18.04; and iptables v1.4.21 on CentOS.

Comment: what's the reason for limiting the number of ip addresses? Doesn't it make more sense to limit the number of tcp connections? With your original request an attacker with a single IP could open any number of tcp connections by opening connections at a rate just a tad slower than the limit. See my updated answer.